# Checkbox not displaying where intended

Tags: html, flask

The page I'm creating  is supposed to display a checkbox (if the user is the admin) followed by the information of the client and a list of projects if there are any associated with that client.

Functionally everything works fine, the problem is that in the cases where there are projects associated with that client, the checkbox, instead of being displayed at the top, for some reason is displayed at the middle of the page before the table. When there is no table (in other words the variable "tiene_proyectos" is false) it is displayed at the top.

I've tried wrapping the checkbox with a div together with the form, puting inside the form, etc., but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is part of the HTML code:

```
    {% if admin %} 
          
        <div class="toolbar">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="modifica"> Enable the update of information
            </label>
        </div>
        
        {% endif %}  
            <form action="/checkclient/{{clientID}}" method="post" id="checkclient">            
                <div id="linea1" class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <label for="username">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="{{cliente[0]['name']}}">
        
                    </div>

... skipped the middle of the form 

            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="address">Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="{{cliente[0]['address']}}" >
            </div>
            {% if admin %}
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="action" value="manual" style="display: inline" >Update</button>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    
    </form>
        {% if tiene_proyectos %}
            <br>
            <hr>
            <hr>
            <br> 
            <p>Table of Projects with Client</p>
            <div id="table-box">
                <table id="dtBasicExample" 
                class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" 
                cellspacing="0" width="100%" 
                data-toggle="table"             
                data-sortable="true" 
                data-toolbar=".toolbar"
                data-pagination="true">
                    <thead>

... skipped rest of table 

    <script type="text/javascript">

... some javascript 

</script>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting (I realize the alignment of the text fields and the button looks pretty bad, but I'm a noob and intend to leave issues with aesthetics for later, however this issue with the checkbox bothered me too much):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeluL.jpg)